# How post add available User Reviews?

Tags: plugins

I have post page and available User Reviews. I have added user reviews with the help of Reviewer plugin.
Added User Reviews with the help of Appearance > Widget. Now, these user reviews will populate appropriately in the post.

My concern is, how these User Reviews added into the post? How would I reach the concept behind it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Its unclear what your asking.

Comment: Hello All, I am using reviewer plugin in my WordPress application. I have 2 questions: 1. How it does work behind the page?  2. Where User Reviews make available like in the application or in the database? Request to provide detailed links.

Comment: Can someone address my questions? Many Thanks!

Comment: I would reach out to the plugin developer.